# Netgear router default SSID not visible after factory reset without ethernet cable

Tags: networking, wifi-configuration

After moving into a new place, the computer wasn't able to see the wireless network name, even after enabling/disabling WiFi on the laptop and factory resetting the router.

Now, the network name of NETGEAR53 is not visible in the wireless network panel.  According to the manual I accessed via the website, it says to use an ethernet cable to connect to the router and access routerlogin.net.  The only issue... The only computers here are Macbook pros that do not contain a wired ethernet cable port, and no adapter is in the house.

Is there any way short of buying an adapter that will allow the router to be configured?

Answer (score 0):

- Be sure your wireless SSID visible or not from your mobile.
- after hard reset some router will gives other default SSID for a seconds, check that too.
- Be sure, maybe there is TurnOFF/ON wifi button on your router.
- You can buy USB ethernet adapter around $3.

The last thing if all of these dose not work for you, and the only thing you have is to throw your router from your window, Make 30-30-30 hard reset and that's "on your risk" this method can remove the firmware completely from NVRAM in some routers

How to make 30-30-30 hard reset:

1. With the unit powered on, press and hold the reset button on back of
   unit for 30 seconds.
2. Without releasing the reset button, unplug the unit and hold reset
   for another 30 seconds.
3. Plug the unit back in STILL holding the reset button a final 30
   seconds.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way short of buying an adapter that will allow the router to
>   be configured?

Yes, you do not need to own a Ethernet card, you just need to use one.

Just about any laptop or desktop has wired ports. You might not own one, but you can take your netgear to work, to friend or family etc etc and then configure it there.  So technically: yes, there is another way.

A second option if to use a spare Wireless Access Point in reverse. Connect with your laptop to the second AP, then use wired from that the the Neargear you are configuring.

Having said that, just buy an USB based NIC. Those are very cheap and you never know when you will need it again.